# How to use different threads for reading, processing and writing in spring-batch step?

Tags: java, concurrency, spring-batch, pipeline, data-processing

As far I understand step in spring batch are divided on 3 stages:

- reading
- process
- writing

According the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#configureStep) The following code shows the concepts:

```
List items = new Arraylist();
for(int i = 0; i < commitInterval; i++){
    Object item = itemReader.read()
    Object processedItem = itemProcessor.process(item);
    items.add(processedItem);
}
itemWriter.write(items);
```

From my view it is much more effective to build a pileline like this:

- 1(or more) thread reads the data
- 1(or more) another_thread are processes the data
- 1(or more) another_then_previous_thread writes the data

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: it's perfectly possible to have several flows/steps, with each their own reader/processor/writer in a single batch. what's stopping you?

Comment: I want to achieve it within single step

Comment: and ... why? batch processes do exactly that, they work with batches. meaning lots of data. If you can split it up in logical blocks, why not? it'll help you avoid OutOfMemory issues.

Comment: This appraoch supposes that read and process are made using the same thread. I want to use different threads for read and process.

Comment: you mean something like this? https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/spring-batch-multi-threaded-step

Comment: As far I understand multithreaded thread doesn't change concept I described(see code from the topic)